# How to solve $(y)^{y'}=(y')^{y+c},c \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

In the case when $ c=0 $ this ode will be  $(y)^{y'}=(y')^{y}$ , let's assume that $y$ and $y'$ are  strictly positive
functions so:

$$(y)^{y'}=(y')^{y} \iff e^{y' \log(y)}= e^{y \log(y')} \iff {y' \log(y)}= {y \log(y')} \iff \frac{y'}{y}=\frac{\log(y')}{\log(y)}$$

I have no idea what to do now? 
Any help please ?

Comment: $\log(y) = t$, so $t' = \frac{y'}{y}$ maybe so ?

Comment: Thank you, this brings us to $ t'=\frac{log(t')}{log(y)}+1$wich still in the darkness:)

Comment: Hi @Fog_convergence. I just did some editing. You can click on the link above my name to see what I did. Primarily, `\log` looks better than `log` and `\iff` is easier to write than `$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $`.

Comment: There is a "trivial" solution to the simplified DE: $y=e^x$.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern [just as trivial: $y=ke^x$.] Note it might not hold that if $y$ is a solution so is $ky.$

Comment: @TheoBendit thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z=\ln(y)$, we have that $zz'=z+\ln(z')$.

If $z'=1$, then $z(x)=x+k$ where $k\in\Bbb R$ i.e. $y(x)=e^{x+k}$.

If $z'\neq1$, then
$$z=\frac{\ln(z')}{z'-1}=f(z')$$
where
$$f:\quad t\mapsto\frac{\ln(t)}{t-1}.$$
$f:\Bbb R^*_+\to\Bbb R^*_+$ is a bijective function, thus $f^{-1}$ is well-defined. Hence, $z'=f^{-1}(z)$. Let $z(0)=a$, by Cauchy–Lipschitz theorem, the equation has a unique maximal solution, and we have
\begin{align}
\frac{z'}{f^{-1}(z)}=1&\implies(\int_a^z\frac{dt}{f^{-1}(t)})'=1\\
&\implies\int_a^z\frac{dt}{f^{-1}(t)}=x\\
&\implies\int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{f^{-1}(z)}\frac{f'(s)}{s}ds=x\tag{1}\\
&\implies I\circ f^{-1}(z)=x+I\circ f^{-1}(a)\tag{2}\\
&\implies z(x)=f\circ I^{-1}(x+I\circ f^{-1}(a))\tag{3}\\
&\implies y(x)=\exp\circ f\circ I^{-1}(x+k)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$(1)$: $t=f(s)$;

$(2)$: $I(x)=-\int_{x}^{+\infty}\frac{f'(s)}{s}ds$;

$(3)$: $I:\Bbb R^*_+\to\Bbb R^*_+$ is bijective;

$(4)$: $k=I\circ f^{-1}(a)$.

The (maximal) domain of $y$ is therefore $(-k,+\infty)$.

(Before assuming $y>0$, note that $y=0$ is also a trivial solution. Generally, for $c\in\Bbb R$, $y=-c$ is the unique constant solution.)

---

The function $I$ has a closed-form expression using $\operatorname {Li}_{2}$:
$$I(x)=\frac1x+f(x)-\left(\operatorname {Li}_{2}(-x)+\frac12\ln^2 x+\frac{\pi^2}6\right).$$